# Extra vertical space in minimal class

Tags: spacing

I am trying to get two pieces of text to align vertically. While I could probably do this with boxes, minipages, or a table, I was trying to adjust the alignment with `\vspace` (somewhat as a learning exercise). In the following MWE the horizontal rules line up with the `article` class, but not with the `minimal` class. With the `minimal` class I am removing too much space (I think).

```
%\documentclass{minimal}
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\newsavebox{\boxa}

\begin{document}
    \savebox{\boxa}{\parbox[b]{\textwidth}{%
        \hrule Xg\par%
        \includegraphics{example-image}\par%
    }}%
    \hrule Xg\par%
    \includegraphics{example-image}\par%
    \vspace{-\ht\boxa}%
    \vspace{-\dp\boxa}%
    \vspace{-\parskip}%
    \nointerlineskip%
    \hrule Xg\par%
    \includegraphics{example-image}\par%
\end{document}
```

I know the `minimal` class does not do a lot of things that are useful, but I don't understand what vertical space I am missing in this example.

Comment: The `minimal` class should never be used for typesetting.

Comment: @egreg I know. In my real document I am using a custom class written by someone else, but I am pretty sure I can recreate my actual problem with the minimal class. I thought it would be easier to demonstrate the issue.

Comment: The problem is that `article` sets `\lineskip` to 1pt, whereas `minimal` has it at 0pt.